# css3 animation visible

Tags: css

I have a problem in css animation.

When a call this animation is working fine.
But after I use delay have a problem.

Problem is: if  Div is invisible after animation is invisible, if is visible after animation is visible.

So I need ==> invisible before animation and visible after.

Code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes ph {
    0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);}
    25% {opacity: 0.9; -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); }
    100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1);}
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you are talking about but I'll try to answer. But are you saying that you want to animate it's opacity?

You can use transitions on different browsers:

```
#object {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity:.5;
}
#object:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

So everytime you onMouseOver and OnMouseOut, the animation will start.

Comment: Sorry my english is no to god.

Comment: Please check this. 
http://jsfiddle.net/sXujn/
After animation, the text is invisible.

Comment: It appears to be the .animate-ph has an opacity:0. So whenever the animation is done, the code will still read the opacity:0 that is why it keeps on disappearing after the animation. Try changing opacity:0 to 1 and see the results if you'll like it. :)

Comment: Thank you.   
But it visible before animation is start. It`ll be working perfekt if invisible before start and visible after animation.

Comment: I have another solution but it includes javascript. But nvm :)

Comment: I found it: 
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;